# How can I change the default theme for every new Opera user on MS Terminal Server?

Tags: windows, opera, themes, terminal-services, terminal-server

Running Opera on a Terminal Server became slow somewhere between Opera version 10 and 30 when graphical themes were introduced as the default theme.

On the other hand Opera 36 does contain a theme with minimal graphics (grey) that updates screens quite fast on a Microsoft Terminal Server.

However having to manually set the grey theme in each and every Terminal Server user is cumbersome.

How can I set the grey Opera theme by default for over Opera user?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up renaming `grey.zip` to `default_theme.zip` in folder `C:\Program Files\opera\36.0.2130.65\resources\standard_themes`.

A few seconds later I found the file C:\Program Files\opera\36.0.2130.65\resources\default_localized_themes.json containing this snippet:

```
"default_localized_themes": {
    "default": "default_theme",
```

So I did undo the file rename operation and edited file default_localized_themes.json to change "default_theme" to "grey" there.